# routing error on accept request button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `dafault` page I have a button `pending request` and when i click on `pending request` button then its went me to the `pending request` page and below is the `pending request` button code

```
<table> 
    <tr>
       <td style="color: #212121;">
          <div class="button">
              <%= button_to "Pending Request", '/pendingrequest', { method: :get, :class => "buttonhome" } %>
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And below is the route of `pending request`:

```
match '/pendingrequest', to: 'static_pages#pending_request', via: 'get'
```

And In the `pending request` page, i am getting requests from users and along with these requests two buttons `accept` and `ignore` are attached i.e below:

```
<table width="50%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="button">
                            <%= button_to "Accept", "/accept", { method: :post, :class => "buttonblck" } %>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                    <td align= "center">
                        <div class="button">
                            <%= button_to "Ignore", '/default', { method: :get, :class => "buttonblck" } %>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

And when i click on `accept` button, my request has been accepted and I am doing accept request work in the create method i.e below:

```
  def create
    @user = Userrequest.select(:RequestFrom).where('RequestTo = ? AND IsApproved = ?', current_user.id, "0")
    requestfrom = @user.RequestFrom
    Userrequest.update_attributes('RequestFrom = ? AND RequestTo = ? AND IsApproved = ?', requestfrom,current_user.id,"1")
    @user_request = Userrequest.new( :RequestFrom => requestfrom , :RequestTo => current_user.id , :IsApproved => "1" , :SkillType => "" )
    @user_request.save
    redirect_to '/default'
  end
```

but when I click on `accept` button it gets me an error below:

```
 No route matches [POST] "/pendingrequest"
```

But `"/pendingrequest"` is the url of `pending request` page, why it give this error on `accept` button. And below is routes of `accept` button:

```
match '/accept', to: 'static_pages#create', via: 'post'
```

Kindly help me, waiting for you reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'd want to use the [path helper](http://blog.kathrynblackley.com/post/72881624696/the-path-helpers-for-a-rails-resourceful-route) for all your buttons. Using the direct path is not very DRY (if you change the routes, you'll have a problem in the future):

```
<%= button_to "Pending Request", pendingrequest_path, { method: :get, :class => "buttonhome" } %>
```

Although I'm not entirely sure what's causing your error, I would look at 3 things to test:

---

**[button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) vs [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)**

`button_to` creates a form which submits each time you click the button. This is relatively unreliable (especially if you include inside another form etc), and so it's best to test using `link_to` to see if that's the error:

```
<%= link_to "Pending Request", '/pendingrequest', method: :get %>
```

---

**Routes**

Secondly, your routes need to be fixed

I would recommend this structure:

```
#config/routes.rb
static = %w(pendingrequest create accept)
for page in static do
    get page, to: "static_page##{page}"
end
```

---

**Methods**

Finally, you need to be sure on your methods

[Rails introduced the HTTP verb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) to a lot of programmers -- meaning you need to make sure you know which verb (method) you should use for your routes

If you're only requesting a page (with `get`), your routes should reflect that. `POST` is mainly for submitting data, not requesting :)